# How to pass current directory as argument to a script?

Tags: python, arguments

Is this possible in Python? I'm working on linux so I'm wondering if there is a way to combine bash commands when invoking the script (something like pwd).

Comment: Why would you? you can access it in the script itself. `import os ; os.getcwd()`

Comment: Of course, you can pipe the output of bash commands to a script which will be readable from `sys.stdin`. Try this in your shell: `pwd | python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdin.read()+'Hello, bash')"` Or even `pwd | python -c "print(input())"` But you should stick `os` and `subprocess` unless you want to make your script something you can pipe or redirect to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the current working directory, you can use:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

If you want to run bash commands, @DeepSpace notes that `subprocess` is preferred to `os.system`, syntax like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("pwd")
```

`os.system` is still functional though, you can do something like this:

```
import os
os.system("pwd")
```

Comment: `os.system` is deprecated. It is recommended to use the `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use [os.curdir](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.curdir), combined with [os.path.abspath](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath)

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)
'/home/msvalkon'
```

Comment: Calling `os.getcwd()` is easier.

Comment: Sure,  but it may not always provide the correct value. I believe `os.getcwd()` will use `$PWD` of your environment which may or may not be correct. Typically is of course.